# Firebase FCM Push notification with Ionic3 Cordova

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try to send a push notification from Firebase FCM to my ionic application, but my application never receives the notification and, after 3 days of search, I can't find any solution! I am going crazy!

1. I've tried to create a new blank application (`ionic start myApp blank`),
2. I've enabled android (`ionic cordova platform add android`)
3. I've created my app in Firebase, downloaded `google-services.json`, and pasted it in my app root folder and in my app `platform/android/app` folder
4. I've installed phonegap-plugin-push (`ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` and `npm install --save @ionic-native/push`)
5. I've pasted this code https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/ in my `app.component.ts`
6. I've added my senderId in android conf (`app.component.ts`)
7. I've imported the push module in `app.module.ts`
8. Everything compiles right, but when I send notification in Firebase (with or without channel id), I don't receive anything

The most incredible thing is that: If I copy my `registrationId` in the console and try to a send test notification (button "test on a device" in FCM on the first step when I create a new message), this test notification is correctly received.

Also Incredible: Notifications has correctly worked 2 hours when I try my first notifications and suddenly stop working without any modification anywhere.

I've tried to restart many new apps from zero and impossible to receive any push notification.

Any idea? Does someone already have the same problem?

PS: Here's my console output:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 430 ms
We have permission to send push notifications
Channel created
Channel deleted
List of channels Array(0) length: 0
Device registered 
Object
registrationId: 
"fbaXyRApJ2k:APA91bHdA5LkxeOfrpNRud0_jetEpb1j93Qn9Bm5TXDp6DpU1TpuWdYHWjKrSdLBaRLizezBJ0Ls1dOr_nYRvOlS4KXSJ6nspaDPKb4nGFUXKFDYclPf24rcYJfGITcImvxcHOpJGHhe"
registrationType: "FCM"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: please try with this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

Comment: `Everything compiles right, but when I send notification in Firebase (with or without channel id), I don't receive nothing` here you're saying that your don't receive your push notification, and here you say that you receive your push notification `If I copy my registrationId in console and try to a send test notification (button "test on a device" in FCM on the first step when I create a new message), this test notification is correctly received.`

Comment: @saperlipopette I receive notification only if I target specific device (with the button "Test on a device" on firebase). It only work with this "test on a device" button who's not usable to send push to all subscribers...

Comment: @kevalnayak, I try to install plugin you suggested, but in the official doc, there is a "backend" var who isn't declared anywhere so i can't compile. Any idea about this ? thank's

Comment: As suggested by Keval, you should try to use the FCM plugin instead. AFAIK the push plugin has been made for Google Cloud Messaging, and I'm not sure that broadcasting a notification to an app was supported. It's a feature of Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: “Backend” should be replaced with your backend service where you will store user to registration id mapping.

Comment: Thank's, you're my hero ! @kevalnayak finaly solve my problem. Note that define a "subject" in firebase when sending a push notification is required to ensure push delivery